# I need a formula that returns how many times an unique value appears in a given date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In a spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheets, I`m trying to solve this:

```
17/02/2012  banana
17/02/2012  banana
17/02/2012  banana
17/02/2012  apple
18/02/2012  apple
18/02/2012  apple
```

I need a formula that returns how many times an unique value appears in a given date.

Example:

```
17/02/2012 - two unique values 
18/02/2012 - one unique value
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: This looks like homework....  What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you would use something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(B5:C10))
```

Assuming your range is in `B5:C10`. You may have to adjust the range.

Comment: I was trying to use =countif based in two criterias but without success. This worked! Thanks